What is Ramanuja's basis to replace "Brahman" by "Atman" in his commentary on Bhagavad Gita 6.27?
BG 6.27

प्रशान्तमनसं ह्येनं योगिनं सुखमुत्तमम् । उपैति शान्तरजसं ब्रह्मभूतमकल्मषम्

Ramanuja's commentary:
https://ia802801.us.archive.org/33/items/gitaramanujagitabhasyadevanagariandenglishrenderingbyswamiadidevanandasriramakrishnamath/GITA-RAMANUJA-GITA-BHASYA-Devanagari-and-English-Rendering-by-Swami-Adidevananda-Sri-RamaKrishna-Math_text.pdf

Supreme happiness, which is of the nature of experience
of the self in its essential nature comes to this Yogin whose
‘mind is at peace,’ i.e., whose mind does not swerve from
the self, whose mind abides in the self; whose impurities are
thereby completely burnt away; whose Rajas is thereby
‘wholly annulled,’ i.e., in whom the quality of Rajas is
destroyed; and who has thus become the Brahman, i.e.,
who remains steady in his essential nature as the Atman.
'HV (for) is added to indicate reason. The meaning is this:
‘On account of the nature of the self which has the form of
supreme bliss.’

Jiva-brahma aikya

Jiva Brahma Aikya" is a Hindu philosophical concept, particularly within the Advaita Vedanta school, which signifies the ultimate unity or oneness of the individual soul ("Jiva") with the universal consciousness ("Brahman")

is proclaimed unequivocally in this verse and Ramanuja seems to be diluting that concept by changing it to unity with the atman. If he is equating brahman with atman that is still Advaitic - this verse allows no room for a personal deity.
